# Fancybox Youtube params cc_lang_pref not working?

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox, fancybox-2, parameters

I'm trying to pass some additional parameters through Fancybox for a video to force the French captions to be shown on an English video. When I include them in the href url, they aren't passed through to the iFrame. When I add :

```
youtube : {
    params : {
        autoplay : 1,
        hl : fr,
        cc_lang_pref : fr,
        cc_load_policy : 1
    }
}
```

to the jquery override, that doesn't work, either. I've tried hl : 'fr' and hl : "fr" and neither work.

Has anyone had any success in passing closed caption parameters through Fancybox?

Comment: Could you provide the youtube link you are using? (it's assumed it should have French captions)

Comment: @JFK One of the videos is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfwcLkLQ_UI. There's a few of them, all being called the same way. Thanks. The video is English, but we've added French captions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass youtube parameters in fancybox, you have to make sure :

1). Load the fancybox media helper js file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{your correct path}/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
```

2). Enable the media helper in your fancybox custom initialization script and pass the youtube parametes inside of it like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            media: {
                youtube: {
                    params: {
                        autoplay: 1,
                        hl: "fr",
                        cc_lang_pref: "fr",
                        cc_load_policy: 1
                    } // params
                } // youtube
            } // media
        } // helpers
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**Notice** that the language property (`fr`) is a string so it must be in quotes.

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

---

An alternative format to initialize the script could be :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            media: true
        }, // helpers
        youtube: {
            autoplay: 1,
            hl: "fr",
            cc_lang_pref: "fr",
            cc_load_policy: 1
        } // youtube
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**Notice** with this format, you don't need the sub-option `params` within the `youtube` option.

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you. I had it set up using the alternate format and didn't realize I didn't need the params within the youtube option.